# Connecting to a third-party service that has a self-signed certificate

Tags: javascript, https, certificate, philips-hue

I am building a website, which access a Philips HUE bridge over local network.

The site is https.

My problem is, that the certificate of the bridge is self-signed, which causes an error when I try to call it:

`Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID`

From the documentation:

> This means that in case you would access the bridge using a browser (e.g. going to https://) the browser will complain that the connection is not secure due to the fact that the certificate has not been certified by a trusted third party, and will ask you whether you want to continue and trust the certificate.
>
> For your application it is best practice to pin (with the bridge-id) the certificate on first connection with the bridge (“trust on first use”) and check upon later contacts with the same bridge.

So the error is expected. But how can I get around it?
I have little experience with certificates, and https for that matter.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Open the Url in your browser, click "advanced" and "continue to unsafe..." (something along those lines).  That will eradicate the "unsafe" reaction *for that browser*.  If you're going to have this problem for every user then you have a problem with the 3rd party that can only be solved with their help.

Comment: I have already done that and it works. But as you say, not a good solution in the long term. And as the 3rd party is Philips, it will take time for them to make this kind of change. I was hoping for a quick faster solution.

Comment: Sadly, it's the only answer, without the 3rd party updating their certificate.

Comment: Actually, you could mask the problem.  Create a service that accesses the bridge and ensure that has access to it, by doing the above.  Then you can access your service without any error, so your website just uses that service instead.  It's a patch, yes, but it will work.